# GCD file monitoring - parent folder(s) changes?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the GCD method of monitoring files for changes. Seems to work fine and I get notifications for file writes, deletes, renames, etc.

Question I have is - how's the right way to approach changes to the *parent* folders for a monitored file?

EX: I want to monitor `abc.txt`

- currently in path `\path\to\something\abc.txt`
- User renames folder `something` to `something_else` so
- file now lives in `\path\to\something_else\abc.txt`

I don't get notifications when the parent folder(s) are renamed or moved because I'm not monitoring them. Am I missing something obvious or do I need to actively monitor the entire set of folders in the hierarchy so parent changes that impact the file are handled appropriately?

Any words of wisdom much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think GCD can do that.  You'll have to go lower-level, with [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html).

Comment: Thank you - I've been reading up on that and it's definitely the way to go.